# How do I access the triggering element using QTip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I have a QTip assigned to an element as follows:

```
$('#myDiv').qtip({
            show: { when: { event: 'click', } },
            hide: { when: { event: 'unfocus' } },
            style: {
                  border: {
                     width: 5,
                     radius: 10
                  },
                  padding: 10, 
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
                  name: 'red' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
            },
            position: {
                corner: {
                 tooltip: 'topMiddle', // Use the corner...
                 target: 'bottomMiddle' // ...and opposite corner
                }
            },
            content: {
               text: self.parent('.qtip').html(),
               title: { text: 'My Title' }
            },

        });
```

Under 'text' in 'content', I am trying to access the innerHTML of the element that triggered this QTip to appear after being clicked on.

However, my current means of `self.parent('.qtip').html()`, as displayed above, is not working.

What is the standard way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: if page has more than one element with qtip, use class selector not id (#)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I later found the solution to this question.

To access properties of the element that triggered the QTip, one must structure the code in this way:

```
$("#container a").each(function() { 
    $(this).qtip({ // QTip code });
});
```

That way, one can use $(this) to access data such as innerHTML of the element that triggered the QTip.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could set it before:

```
var text = $('#myDiv').text();
```

And use it inside the object:

```
text: text,
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it didn't get the contents of the div with ID 'myDiv.'

Comment: That didn't do anything oddly. My solution is below. Thanks!